# Why does for-loop behave differently when counting up vs counting down?

Tags: c++, for-loop, factorial

This is a homework question which I recently revisited. It requires me not to use `cmath` and writes a function to evaluate `cos pi/3`. The code is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double power(double x, int b) {
    if (b>1) return x*power(x,b-1);
    else if (b==0) return 1;
    else return x;
}

double cosine(double x, int k) {
    double tmp=0;
    for (int n=0; n<=k; n++) {
        tmp += power(-1,n) / factorial(2*n) * power(x,2*n);
    }
    return tmp;
}

int main() {
    double x=3.1415/3; 
    int k=100;
    cout << cosine(x,k) << endl;
}
```

I have written two versions of `double factorial(int a)` with for-loops.

One counts up and successfully outputs `0.500027` :

```
double factorial(int a) {
    double tmp=1;
    for (int i=1; i<=a; i++) {
        tmp*=i;
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

The other one counts down and outputs `inf` (but successfully evaluate 4!=24):

```
double factorial(int a) {
    double tmp=a;
    for (int i=a; i>=1; i--) {
        tmp*=i;
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

**Why does the count down loop fail to give a convergent output?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `factorial()` multiplies `a` twice. Try this:

```
double factorial(int a) {
    double tmp=1; // use 1 instead of a
    for (int i=a; i>=1; i--) {
        tmp*=i;
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Note that using `double tmp=a;` and initializing `i` to `a-1` is not good  because it will make `factorial(0) = 0`, while `factorial(0)` should be 1.

The first implementation also multiplies 1 twice, but multiplying 1 doesn't affect the result.

Comment: Works for `double tmp=1;` but still `inf` for `int i=a-1`. Why?

Comment: @user2513881 Try testing `factorial()` without using `cosine()`.

Comment: `factorial(10)` gives 3.6288e+06. But yes, `factorial(0)` is a problem and causes 'divison by zero' when n=0 in the for-loop of `cosine(x,k)`.